# How can I loop for a value filter for the output

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular, typescript

I get an array return that looks like this

```
{
    "pkinfopointDetail": 10,
    "fkinfopointTyp": 4,
    "bezeichnung": "Lotsenweiterbildung - Gemeindegebiet Scharnstein",
    "headerBezeichnung": "Einsätze & Veranstaltungen",
    "url": null,
    "parameter": null,
    "name": "Lotsenweiterbildung ",
    "pfad": "https://www.ff-scharnstein.at/infosystem/assets/lot1.jpg",
    "top": true,
    "gueltigVon": "2021-04-17T00:00:00",
    "gueltigBis": "2099-12-31T00:00:00"
},
{
    "pkinfopointDetail": 11,
    "fkinfopointTyp": 4,
    "bezeichnung": "Verkehrsunfall eingeklemmte Person B120 Bereich Rauleithen",
    "headerBezeichnung": "Einsätze & Veranstaltungen",
    "url": null,
    "parameter": null,
    "name": "VU Rauleiten",
    "pfad": "https://www.ff-scharnstein.at/infosystem/assets/vu_rauleiten (1).png",
    "top": true,
    "gueltigVon": "2021-04-13T00:00:00",
    "gueltigBis": "2099-12-31T00:00:00"
},
{
    "pkinfopointDetail": 11,
    "fkinfopointTyp": 4,
    "bezeichnung": "Verkehrsunfall eingeklemmte Person B120 Bereich Rauleithen",
    "headerBezeichnung": "Einsätze & Veranstaltungen",
    "url": null,
    "parameter": null,
    "name": "VU Rauleiten",
    "pfad": "https://www.ff-scharnstein.at/infosystem/assets/vu_rauleiten(1).jpg",
    "top": false,
    "gueltigVon": "2021-04-13T00:00:00",
    "gueltigBis": "2099-12-31T00:00:00"
}
```

now I would like to output after the name "pkinfopointDetail" everything which is e.g. 10. After 10sec it should then output the 11.

```
async setUrl() {
const timer = ms => new Promise(res => setTimeout(res, ms))
for (let index = 0; index < this.infopointDetail.length; index++) {
  this.data.changeMessage(this.infopointDetail[index].headerBezeichnung);
  if (this.infopointDetail[index].parameter === 'top') {
    this.urlSafe = this.infopointDetail[index].url;
    await timer(5000);
  }
}
```

that was my first approach but there I get all entries. What do I have to do that this works.

Here is a snippet example

[Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-eb8cby?file=src%2Fapp%2Feinsaetze%2Feinsatz-veranstaltung%2Feinsatz-veranstaltung.component.ts)

Comment: If you remove all the `this` from the code, you could make a [mcve] using the `[<>]` snippet editor

Comment: produce a stackblitz

Comment: @Toxy For this a `[<>]` stacksnippet would work just fine. It is not really Angular related, just plain JS

Answer (score 0):

Dont know why you have `parameter === 'top'` condition as it is always returning false that is why its not working. and if you need it as for your bussiness login then try call `await timer(infopointDetail[index].pkinfopointDetail * 1000);` inside it.

Try this :

```js
const infopointDetail = [{
    "pkinfopointDetail": 10,
    "fkinfopointTyp": 4,
    "bezeichnung": "Lotsenweiterbildung - Gemeindegebiet Scharnstein",
    "headerBezeichnung": "Einsätze & Veranstaltungen",
    "url": null,
    "parameter": null,
    "name": "Lotsenweiterbildung ",
    "pfad": "https://www.ff-scharnstein.at/infosystem/assets/lot1.jpg",
    "top": true,
    "gueltigVon": "2021-04-17T00:00:00",
    "gueltigBis": "2099-12-31T00:00:00"
  },
  {
    "pkinfopointDetail": 11,
    "fkinfopointTyp": 4,
    "bezeichnung": "Verkehrsunfall eingeklemmte Person B120 Bereich Rauleithen",
    "headerBezeichnung": "Einsätze & Veranstaltungen",
    "url": null,
    "parameter": null,
    "name": "VU Rauleiten",
    "pfad": "https://www.ff-scharnstein.at/infosystem/assets/vu_rauleiten (1).png",
    "top": true,
    "gueltigVon": "2021-04-13T00:00:00",
    "gueltigBis": "2099-12-31T00:00:00"
  },
  {
    "pkinfopointDetail": 11,
    "fkinfopointTyp": 4,
    "bezeichnung": "Verkehrsunfall eingeklemmte Person B120 Bereich Rauleithen",
    "headerBezeichnung": "Einsätze & Veranstaltungen",
    "url": null,
    "parameter": null,
    "name": "VU Rauleiten",
    "pfad": "https://www.ff-scharnstein.at/infosystem/assets/vu_rauleiten(1).jpg",
    "top": false,
    "gueltigVon": "2021-04-13T00:00:00",
    "gueltigBis": "2099-12-31T00:00:00"
  }
];

const changeMessage = str => console.log(str);
const urlSafe = url => console.log(new URL(url));
let infopointDetailBottomImgArr = [];

async function setUrl() {
  const timer = ms => new Promise(res => setTimeout(res, ms))
  for (let index = 0; index < infopointDetail.length; index++) {
    changeMessage(infopointDetail[index].headerBezeichnung);
    if (infopointDetail[index].parameter === 'top') {
      urlSafe(infopointDetail[index].url);
      const arr = this.infopointDetail.filter(item => {
          return (
            item.pkinfopointDetail ===
              infopointDetail[index].pkinfopointDetail && !item.top
          );
        });
        infopointDetailBottomImgArr = arr;
        console.log(arr);
        await timer(this.infopointDetail[index].pkinfopointDetail * 1000);
    }
   
  }
}

setUrl();
```

Comment: This is for the first Picture for the Top Position. I have past an Link to Stackblitz. It should show 3 Picture first an then the other 3 Picture from the other ID

Comment: Thx for the sample. But i would like to show all entrys with pkinfopointDetail = 10 and 10 sec delay the entrys with pkinfoPointDetail = 11 (its an Imagegallery)

Comment: sorry but i am not able understand what you need.

Comment: I get an array like the one above. There I have a key 'pkinfoPointDetail' e.g. pkinfoPointDetail=10 and pkinfoPointDetail=11. Now I should output everything in the array with pkinfoPointDetail=10 first. That are e.g. 3 photos. After 10 seconds I have to output pkinfoPointDetail=11 which is e.g. 4 photos.

Comment: Nobody an Idea for my Problem

Comment: i tried in your stackblitz its working but at issue is its taking 10 sec to show the first image right ??

Comment: No the problem is that I want to show 3 images first and after 10sec the other 3 images. So all the PKInfopointDetail have the same number.

Comment: okay but wheres the 3 image will come from ?? your object dont have any img expect `pfad` property which is already used in `this.urlSafe`

Comment: Yes this is from another query. That is my question how I can implement that I get the 3 images in an array for output and then the next. How do I have to do that? Thanks

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/231415/discussion-between-toxy-and-storm-tec).